# MySQL inet_aton() returning null sporadically

Tags: mysql, ip-address, percona

I'm inserting data into a log table, including an IP address. For some reason, the IP column is sometimes NULL'ed. In most cases (99.9% of all records) the IP is recorded properly.

The IPs get stored in an unsigned INT column, using the inet_aton() function. This translates an IP address from it's written dot-separated form (zzz.xxx.yyy.www) to its numeric form.

The MySQL documentation states the following regarding INET_ATON() and NULLs:

> INET_ATON() returns NULL if it does not understand its argument.
>
> INET_ATON() may or may not return a non-NULL result for short-form IP addresses (such as '127.1' as a representation of '127.0.0.1').

I've been logging the data flowing into the query, and have verified that the parameters being bound do in fact contain the IP address and not null. They IP addresses look fine, and if I manually run a

> SELECT INET_ATON('zzz.yyy.xxx.www');

the result is a numeric representation, as expected.

For completeness, the code (note: removed seemingly irrelevant columns):

```
/* @var $conn PDO */
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
'INSERT INTO subscription_log(
    email, groupid, subscribe_ip
) VALUES (
    :email,
    :groupid,
    inet_aton(:label_subscribe_ip),
)');
$result = $stmt->execute($params);

// With the following input for $params (print_r):
Array
(
    [email] => user@domain.com
    [groupid] => 51299
    [label_subscribe_ip] =>  145.222.138.151
)
```

Finally, though I doubt it's relevant, MySQL version information:

```
version = 5.5.27-28.1
version_comment = Percona Server (GPL), Release 28.1
version_compile_machine = x86_64
version_compile_os = Linux
```

To me, it's mystifying. Any suggestions on how to go about further debugging this, anyone?

Comment: Are you 100% sure no extra whitespace or non printable character gets added to input? Because you have two spaces here `[label_subscribe_ip] =>  145.222.138.151`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have whitespace (or non printable character) added to your input.

Assuming you posted literal output here:

```
Array
(
    [email] => user@domain.com
    [groupid] => 51299
    [label_subscribe_ip] =>  145.222.138.151
)
```

You have two spaces before `145.` meaning that the real input is `_145.222.138.151` (with a space in the beginning).

Try using [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) before adding ip to parameters list.